# is not a class or namespace name

Tags: c++, class, precompiled-headers

I know this question has been asked and answered before, but none of the solutions seem to have worked for me, and my compiler is acting really weird with this error.

When I try and compile my code I get numerous errors such as these:

```
Error   1   error C2653: 'TargetList' : is not a class or namespace name    c:\projects\arcturus\augmentedreality\targetlist.cpp    5   1   AugmentedReality
Error   2   error C2065: 'Target' : undeclared identifier   c:\projects\arcturus\augmentedreality\targetlist.cpp    5   1   AugmentedReality
Error   3   error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'target'  c:\projects\arcturus\augmentedreality\targetlist.cpp    5   1   AugmentedReality
Error   4   error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\projects\arcturus\augmentedreality\targetlist.cpp    5   1   AugmentedReality
Error   5   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  c:\projects\arcturus\augmentedreality\targetlist.cpp    6   1   AugmentedReality
Error   6   error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?) c:\projects\arcturus\augmentedreality\targetlist.cpp    6   1   AugmentedReality
```

I encountered this kind of error when compiling my project before, but it mystically disappeared. I was trying to fix the problem, and after a while it just started to work again after I reverted all of my changes.

I think this may be a problem with my precompiled header, as this error popped up after I had tried to fix an error with my PCH not working properly.

Here is my code (and I know it isn't that well designed, just trying to get it to work at the moment :P):

**StdAfx.h**

```
#pragma once

#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
```

**Target.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "Position.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Target
{
public:
    Target();
    Target(std::string shortName, std::string longName, Position position);
    ~Target();

    bool UpdateTargetData(Position currentPosition);

    std::string mShortName;
    std::string mLongName;
    Position mPosition;
    double mDistance;
    double mHorizontalBearing;
    double mVerticalBearing;
};
```

**Target.cpp**

```
#include "Target.h"
#include "stdafx.h"

bool Target::UpdateTargetData(Position currentPosition)
{
    mDistance = currentPosition.GetDistance(mPosition);
    mHorizontalBearing = currentPosition.GetHorizontalBearing(mPosition);
    mVerticalBearing = currentPosition.GetVerticalBearing(mPosition);

    return true;
}
```

**TargetList.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "Target.h"

class TargetList
{
public:
    TargetList();
    ~TargetList();

    bool AddTarget(Target target);
    bool GetTarget(std::string shortName, Target& returnTarget);
    bool RemoveTarget(std::string shortName);

private:
    std::vector<Target> mTargets;
};
```

**TargetList.cpp**

```
#include "TargetList.h"
#include "Target.h"
#include "stdafx.h"

bool TargetList::AddTarget(Target target)
{
    if (GetTarget(target.mShortName, Target()) != false)
    {
        mTargets.push_back(target);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

bool TargetList::GetTarget(std::string shortName, Target& returnTarget)
{
    std::vector<Target>::iterator iterator;

    for (iterator = mTargets.begin(); iterator < mTargets.end(); iterator++)
    {
        if ((*iterator).mShortName == shortName)
        {
            returnTarget = (*iterator);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

bool TargetList::RemoveTarget(std::string shortName)
{
    std::vector<Target>::iterator iterator;

    for (iterator = mTargets.begin(); iterator < mTargets.end(); iterator++)
    {
        if ((*iterator).mShortName == shortName)
        {
            mTargets.erase(iterator);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Would you care to tell us **where** the error occurs, or is this part of the test? Also, the `#include "stdafx.h"` should probably go at the very top.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

PCH (i.e `stdafx.h`) should be included first in the `.cpp` file. So do this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"     //this should be included first!
#include "TargetList.h"
#include "Target.h"
```

See these topics:

- [About stdafx.h missing in my compiler(mingw32 on windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408583/a-question-about-stdafx-h)
- [What does this MSVC++ compile error mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320436/what-does-this-msvc-compile-error-mean)

Comment: Or include both of Target-files in `stdafx.h` itself.

Comment: Yep, this worked, thank you so much.

Do you know why it caused errors in some files, and not in others? Just curious.

Comment: @Nick: Go through the links to know that in detail.

Comment: Perhaps it is rather so that others have time to write a better answer.